# I just got a 429 error on a calendar request, my requests are not more active than 1 or 2 a minute

Tags: google-calendar-api

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest returned "Too Many Requests">

I just got a 429 error on a calendar request, my requests are not more active than 1 or 2 a minute. I stopped my app and tried to do a single call, it also failed I have retrying 1 2 3 4 hours later still fails. any help would be appreciated. As everyone says nothing changed and has worked for over a year. Thank you,

Joel

Here is the section in question

```
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                    maxResults=50, singleEvents=True,
                                    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like this has been reported on Google's Issue Tracker and is an active issue.**

What you can do is to star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159368649) and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.

Comment: thank you so much. I was pretty sure I didn't screw this one up.